# React Native and storing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

What is the correct/more idiomatic way/process to take JSON from a users database (Firebase) and store that locally on an app.

The app is a game and the game data and the user data are stored in section JSON so I want to download a section at a time when the user completes one section.

any links and code sampled would be greatly appreciated and bonus points for a workflow diagram.

P.s I'm new to all this so really looking for advice to help me develop my skills.

Thank you.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't really have an idiomatic approach.  You should simply write the code that satisfies the requirements of your app.  Every app's use of any given database will be different.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your reply. I just didnt want to get started before I knew the "best practice" so to speak.